# how to find row that have lower case string MySQL query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How to find lower case string on same column 
my table Collation latin1_swedish_ci

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`  WHERE  UPPER(column_name) != column_name
```

Comment: does above query didnt work?

Comment: You can use a hash of the column and compare that with a hash of the column's upper case equivalent. There are many kinds of hash, but I imagine any would do.

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed evidently. The OP is using a ci collation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below out. This would give you all the column entries with lowercase string-

```
select 'column' from 'table' where 'column' regexp binary '^[a-z]*$';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to say COLLATE `latin1_swedish_ci`

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`  WHERE  UPPER(column_name) != column_name
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE UPPER([column_name]) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci !=[column_name]
```

should first check the default collation for respective database and the column... and pass in the default collation with the query expression